# I'm getting "Unable to cast" error on getting selected items on listbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listbox

I have these error on li only when running, I'm using Visual Studio.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'.

```
 private void btnRunReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     rptTopBottom.selDepartment = GetDepartments();
 }

 private string GetDepartments()
 {
     string selDept = "";
     foreach (ListItem li in listDepartment.Items)
     {
         if (li.Selected)
         {
             selDept += li.Value + ',';
         }
     }
     selDept = selDept.Substring(0, selDept.Length - 1);
     return selDept;
 }
```

Comment: What line the code is breaking on? Somewhere you trying to use a `String` as if it was a `ListItem`

Comment: is this winforms or ASP.NET?

Comment: Winforms @CasparKleijne

Comment: Can you show rptTopBottom?

Comment: ListItem doesn't exist for WinForms, listDepartment.Items in Winforms does not return Listitem but object

Comment: public string selDepartment { get; set; }

and for my stored procedure
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@selDepartment", this.selDepartment);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'.

indicates that this line

```
foreach (ListItem li in listDepartment.Items)
```

is the failing because `listDepartment.Items` seems to contain elements of type `string` instead of type `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem`.

You are using a `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox`. This listbox' [`Items`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property is an object collection that contains exactly the objects you added. It does not contain `System.Web.UI.WebControl.ListItem`s.

You should use the [`ListBox.SelectedItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property instead:

```
foreach (string s in listDepartment.SelectedItems)
    selDept += s + ',';
```

Comment: it worked but it says Procedure or function  has too many arguments specified on my report form.

Comment: Well, I don't know your report form or which method you are passing too many arguments to. Sounds like a new question, so you could open a new question for that.

Comment: Thanks i just forgot to include sql Stored Procedure.. It's ok now yay !!